# What are situations when a shared smart pointer is needed and unique can't be used?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Seems like maybe shared pointers could be useful across threads when both pointers are accessing same object.

But otherwise I can't think of a single time when I would need a shared pointer and a unique pointer wouldn't do the trick. Can you?

Comment: Additionally to the shared ownership, `shared_ptr` also has a _type-erased deleter_, which might be useful in some cases. (For instance, you cannot create a vector of `unique_ptr` objects with different deleters.)

Comment: @DanielLangr, to be clear, `unique_ptr` may also have a type-erased deleter.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Yes, but such type-erasure is not provided by `unique_ptr` itself.

Comment: Apart from Acorns good answer, there are some uglier use cases - prevent leaks in legacy code without putting the effort to cleanly implement ownership semantics, quickly porting code from other languages like Java. Mostly there are better alternatives, e.g. using a shared_ptr parameter 'poisons' your function declarations and should be avoided, even if the caller uses shared_ptr (with such an interface, each caller has to use it), see Guideline R.30 - http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r30-take-smart-pointers-as-parameters-only-to-explicitly-express-lifetime-semantics

Answer (score 3):

> What are situations when a shared smart pointer is needed and unique can't be used?

Every time you need shared ownership.

It should not be a common occurrence, but there are some cases that stand out, like graph-like structures (including cycles), some async programming patterns, long-lived objects with no clear owner and the desire to avoid globals, etc.

Comment: The things become even more interesting when the `weak_ptr` is used. And a non-trivial `weak_ptr` cannot exist without a `shared_ptr` constructed.